Are those pads on Raspberry pi Zero related to USB C or something?
I was playing with my RP Zero 2w and notice that it has some pads (check image, over yellow rectangles) for soldering some kind of connector like usb-c / Display Port/ HDMI or others.
It has 2 big pads for ground (maybe for mounting the shield of the connector) and 8 small pads for the pins. Quickly I started my google search. This pads are also on my Zero W

My search has returned only this pad map:

Where the desired zone is not covered. Does someone knowns what is theusage of those pads? What can I solder there?

After a long search, this seems to be Videocore JTAG connector, used for debug operations on production.
source here
